# Bind selected DataGrid row to textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to bind a textbox to a selected `DataGrid`. I have already binded the list to a datagrid but now I would like to bind the `TextBox`text to the `DataGrid`selected row so its content will be placed into the `TextBox`

```
txtOccArea.DataContext = hegData;
//hegData is a list of an object
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?? Please post some code

Comment: Just updated my post

Comment: You should actually consider binding selected value of List to the value of TextBox

Comment: How would I get the selected value in the list ? using the datagrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new class like this ( I hope you are using MVVM ).

```
public class YourViewVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region Fields

    private object selectedDataGridCell;
    private string textBoxContent;
    private List<YourObject> dataGridSource;

    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public object SelectedDataGridCell
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedDataGridCell;

        }
        set
        {
            if (this.selectedDataGridCell != value)
            {
                this.selectedDataGridCell = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDataGridCell");
            }
        }
    }


    public string TextBoxContent
    {
        get
        {
            return this.textBoxContent;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.textBoxContent != value)
            {
                this.textBoxContent = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TextBoxContent");
            }
        }
    }

    public List<YourObject> DataGridSource
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dataGridSource;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.dataGridSource != value)
            {
                this.dataGridSource = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Source");
            }
        }

    }

    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}
```

In your view, just modify it to:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataGridCell}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding TextBoxContent}"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

You need to add the `INotifyPropertyChanged` so the `TextBox` knows when the selection has changed.

If you need to set the DataGridSource to your `hegData` list, just create a constructor and set the property there like this:

```
public YourViewVM(List<YourObject> hegData)
    {
        this.DataGridSource = hegData;
    }
```

And where you create it just call it like:

```
YourViewVM yourViewVM = new YourViewVM(hegData)
```

Comment: Thanks for assisting!

Comment: @Hancs So glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the value in the TextBox it will be ok to bind in XAML. Try this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding hegData}"/>
<TextBox Text={Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=MyGrid}/>
```

If you actually need to alter the Selected Item, I think you should define a SelectedListItem property in your ViewModel and bind the TextBox's text to this property.

ViewModel:

```
public List<object> hegData {get;set;}
public object SelectedListItem {get;set;}
```

View:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding hegData}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListItem}"/>
<TextBox Text={Binding SelectedListItem}/>
```